# Ruby: Combine string and get value of Combined string variable

Tags: ruby

I define float

```
enquire_balance_outstanding_score=0.7
```

Then, I combined text and get same name of variable "enquire_balance_outstanding_score"

```
text=enquire-balance_outstanding
ref_score=0.0
ref_score= (text.tr('-','_')+"_score").to_f
```

I want value of ref_score to be 0.7 but when I run, it returns **0.0**.

How to get this variable value??

Answer (score 1):

`String#to_f` converts, say, `"0.7"` to 0.7. It does not convert `"enquire_balance_outstanding_score"` to 0.7; in other words, `to_f` does not resolve variable values.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [`Hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Hash.html)?

```
values = {'enquire_balance_outstanding_score' => 0.7}
text = 'enquire-balance_outstanding'
values[text.tr('-','_')+"_score"]
# => 0.7
```

You can use [`Kernel#eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval), but this is **not recommended** because `eval` can execute abitrary expression.

```
enquire_balance_outstanding_score = 0.7
text = 'enquire-balance_outstanding'
eval text.tr('-','_')+"_score"
# => 0.7
```

Comment: @user3214044, As I mentioned, I **don't recommend** to use it.